# ASP.NET and diacritics

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, diacritics

I intend to create asp.net pages using Visual Studio 2008. Preferably, the pages should be fully compliant with XHTML standard. How should I include the diacritics into the page content (no need to use diacritics in URLs)? Should I use character references (the ones with "&"), or just writing them directly form the keyboard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ensure the correct character set encoding for the page, UTF-8 usually covers most western alphabets and UTF-16 for double byte characters required by languages that use [ideograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideogram).

In the HEAD element of the page you will need some form of the following tag;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

You will also need to ensure you have the correct DOCTYPE specified;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This is well covered by the [W3C Character Sets Tutorial](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/)